# How old is Bo-Katan in The Mandalorian?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

We see Bo-Katan multiple times in TCW, especially season 7.  She appears in Rebels several years later, and then in The Mandalorian.  And she looks *very* young for her age, almost as if she's hardly aged.

[image]

There are 28 years between TCW season 7 and The Mandalorian season 2.  The actress who portrays Bo-Katan is 41, but Bo-Katan obviously wasn't 13 in season 7.

So how old was she in TCW?  She was an active fighter and part of Deathwatch for a while, so it seems unlikely, from that and her apparent age, that she was a teenager when she first joined.  If she was in her early 20's in season 7 then she would be in her late 40's in Mandalorian, which sort of fits but still is strange for her age when she would've joined Deathwatch.  Is there an exact answer of how old she is by The Mandalorian?

Comment: https://www.starwars.com/series/star-wars-rebels/heroes-of-mandalore-trivia-gallery - Slide 5

Comment: @Valorum  That article just says that Bo-Katan is aged by 18 years from TCW to Rebels, since that's how much time has passed.  It doesn't specify her exact age at either point.

Comment: I would imagine that star wars tech face cream would keep one looking young for a long time

Comment: Hence why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @Valorum Gotcha, sorry if that came off as argumentative.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

### 51 at the absolute minimum, more likely 61 or older

*Star Wars: Timelines* has this as its earliest entry mentioning Bo-Katan:

> ###### c.42 BBY: A new path
>
> The Mandalorian Civil War ends with Satine's New Mandalorians ascendant, though traditionalists—**including Satine's sister Bo-Katan**—organize to resist her rule.
>
> <sub>[*Star Wars: Timelines*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Timelines), page 46: The Republic Crumbles; emphasis added</sub>

This confirms that Bo-Katan had not only joined Death Watch by ~42 BBY, but took part in their resistance to Satine's leadership. Her first appearance in *The Mandalorian* Season 2 takes place in 9 ABY (again per *Timelines*), so there's a span of ~51 years between these events.

It's unclear how old Bo-Katan was at the time of the Mandalorian Civil War, but if she was somehow an honorary member of Death Watch as an infant, she'd be around 50 by the time of *The Mandalorian*, and in the more likely case she was closer to 10-20 years old, she'd be ~60-70 in *The Mandalorian*.